# How to import a .py file in all files?

Tags: python

Is it possible to import a test.py file in whole project instead of importing it in each file?
for example calling it some where in start.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

even if it is ... (which in programming is almost always the case) a better question is why would you want to.

It would be difficult to do, and it adds nothing... in fact it can severely hinder development, and you may experience very strange bugs that become very hard to track down

---

[edit based on OP comment]

your use case sounds like you just want it to be in builtins

start.py

```
import __builtin__
import my_weird_test_class
__builtin__.tester = my_weird_test_class
from main_entry import main
main()
```

now in any file you can use

```
tester.do_something()
```

without importing tester or whatever

but as I said this tends to be a very **bad idea**... it is much better to explicitly import it in all your files ...

Comment: I have developed a debug class which provide some facilities to debugging. I want to add it to all of my files and after that remove that. so I think the best idea is to act like this. any idea?

Comment: I did this once with localization stuff, because I thought it was a good idea ... take it from me this is not a good idea and will lead to no end to headaches...

Answer (score 2):

No.

However, suppose you have three modules, `a.py`, `b.py`, and `c.py`. Further, assume that `c.py` imports `b`, and `b.py` imports `a`. Then in `c.py`, you can refer to items in `a` using

```
b.a.foo
```

since `b` imported `a` into its namespace.

Comment: +1 since you are correct ... however there is very rarely a valid reason to do this ... python wont re-import an already loaded module ... it just points to it

Comment: I have developed a debug class which provide some facilities to debugging. I want to add it to all of my files and after that remove that. so I think the best idea is to act like this. any idea?

Comment: The time it takes to add, then remove (or simply comment out), `import mydebugclass` from a file you want to debug is going to be negligible compared to the amount of time you actually spend debugging.